# Why sometimes I get "Cursor not returned from Query" from a valid select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some valid select statements that when I send to MSSQL2005 sometimes return the error "Cursor not returned from Query".

It happens with different queries that work fine 99% of the time, and the only thing they all have in common is the use of several joins and some group by. Pretty standard queries.

How can I trace this and find out what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It would probably help if you included some code.

Comment: @Tom, they are standard select queries, with joins, a group by and a where clause and they work 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(SQL.80).aspx) can capture the SQL statements sent across the wire.

Capture the actual SQL sent and try running from SQL Server Management Studio.

How is your code executing the SQL statement(s)? I suspect that's where the problem is rather than the SQL itself.